# ElasticSearch Advanced Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently have documents indexed with the following structure:

```
"ProductInteractions": {
    "properties": {
        "SKU": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Sources": {
            "properties": {
                "Source": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to aggregate on results when searching over this type. I initially just wanted the terms from the `Source` field, which was easy. I just used a `terms` aggregations for the `Source` field.

Now I would like to aggregate the `Type` field as well. However, the types are related to the sources. For example, I could have two `Sources` like this:

```
{
    "Source": "The Store",
    "Type": "Purchase"
}
```

and

```
{
    "Source": "The Store",
    "Type": "Return"
}
```

I want to show the different types and their counts for each different source. In other words, I would want my response to be something like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "Sources": [
            {
                "Key": "The Store",
                "DocCount": 2,
                "Aggregations": {
                    "Types": [
                        {
                            "Key": "Purchase",
                            "DocCount": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "Return",
                            "DocCount": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get these sub-aggregations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is but you need to slightly change your mapping to make your fields `not_analyzed``

```
"ProductInteractions": {
    "properties": {
        "SKU": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Sources": {
            "properties": {
                "Source": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "Type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following aggregation in order to get what you want:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "sources": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Sources.Source"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "types": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Sources.Type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.